# Double buffer on bash

Tags: bash

I have a script with a loop printing info every N seconds

```
function exit_loop
{
    tput rmcup
    tput cnorm
    exit 0
}

function main_loop
{
    tput smcup
    tput civis

    trap exit_loop SIGINT

    while [ true ]; do
        sleep $DELAY &
        clear
        # do things and print
        wait
    done
}
```

the previous work fine but when the script is printing is ugly between refesh, exist some kind of double buffer.

#### Note

my script use colors in output with `echo -e` and `printf` sentences

Comment: If the problem is that your script executes slowly, why not print to a file and then `clear; cat file` once you've finished creating it?

Comment: the script finish very quickly

Comment: Then explain what you mean by "is ugly between refresh", if it's not a question of speed?

Comment: example when you use the command `watch` you can't see the refresh

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a double-buffer is rici's answer:  do all your `# do things and print` stuff with output redirected into a temp file, *before* you clear the screen; then clear the screen and cat the temp file.

Or you can move the cursor to the top of the screen without clearing it and then overwrite what's there.  However, then you're responsible for clearing out any remaining old text that extended past the end of the new text.